# Placing API calls with test Credit Cards in BlueSnap Sandbox?

Tags: api, credit-card, applepay, wallet, bluesnap

I'm trying to place API calls to charge shoppers in BlueSnap's Sandbox - using a simple [Auth-Capture call](https://developers.bluesnap.com/v8976-XML/docs/auth-capture) and I'm not sure which test cards I can use:

```html
  <credit-card>
      <card-number>4263982640269299</card-number>
      <security-code>837</security-code>
      <expiration-month>02</expiration-month>
      <expiration-year>2018</expiration-year>
  </credit-card>
```

I'm looking for reference on:
 1. Can I just use any test card I find on Google? 
 2. Can I test card failures somehow?
 3. Do online wallets work with the same type of cards?

Answer (score 2):

I asked BlueSnap's Support team and this is what they say:

- It doesn't matter if you use API or not - also the BlueSnap console (UI) allows using test cards.
- Sometimes you can use Google to search for test cards - but if you're testing with BlueSnap, the best option is to use [this page](https://developers.bluesnap.com/docs/test-credit-cards) for reference.
- The provides you with different card brands & currency scenarios and also you can choose specific cards to get the result you want (success or failure).
- Be sure to scroll all the way to the bottom and see the Apple Pay test cards - for other wallets you can keep on using the cards at the top table.